# php echo week number counting days out of a full year

Tags: php, echo, mktime

This is a working demo of my script : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f9b-cmr

What i would like to do is display the day then the amount of days that day has appeared in the year and then the total of times it will appear in the whole year.

example today is Tuesday 32nd tuesday out of 53 in 2013

tomorrow is wednesday 32nd wednesday out of 52 in 2013

some days appear 52 times a year and some appear 53 times.

The problem: Tuesday should display 32 out of 53 for 2013 but it displays 32 of 52.

if i change mktime to 12,31 then it displays 01 instead of 53.

```
<?php
    $weekNumber = date("W");
    $weekTotal = date("W", mktime(0,0,0,12,28,date("Y")));
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        for($i=0; $i<1; $i++){ 
            $weekNumber =  "".date("W", mktime(0, 0, 0, ($_POST["month"]), ($_POST["date"]), ($_POST["year"])))."";
            $weekTotal =  "".date("W", mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, 28, ($_POST["year"])))."";
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form id="date" method='post'>
        <p>Date:
        <input type="text" id="date" name ="date" size="10" placeholder="1 - 31"/>
        Month:
        <input type="text" id="month" name ="month" size="10" placeholder="1 - 12"/>
        Year:
        <input type="text" id="year" name ="year" size="15" placeholder="101 - 9999"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"/></p>
    </form>

    <p><?php echo "It is week number "; echo $weekNumber; echo " out of ".$weekTotal."";?></p>
```

Comment: Because 365/7 = 52 weeks + 1 day, +2 days in leap years.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.  You've stated what you are trying to do and posted code, but didn't specify the trouble you are having.

Comment: @BlargleMonster in the demo it says this week is 32 out of 52 but its not as there are 53 tuesdays in 2013 os it should say 32 out of 53. I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: Could it be because your mktime() ends on Dec 28, while the final Tuesday in 2013 is Dec 31?

Comment: @GreatBigBore I though that but it just seems to display 01 instead of 53

Comment: Post your latest version to phpfiddle. When I run your fiddle, Aug 6 2013 says 'It is week number 52 out of 52'.

Comment: @GreatBigBore Here is the latest code [link](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/v1k-94r)

Answer (score 0):

date("W") returns the ISO-8601 week number, which has some interesting technicalities near the end of the year. From the wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#Last_week):

> The last week of the ISO week-numbering year is the week before week
>   01; in accordance with the symmetry of the definition, equivalent
>   definitions are:
>
> - the week with the year's last Thursday in it
> - the week ending with the Sunday which is nearest in time to 31 December
> - etc. (see the wiki page for more)